# Dynamic Tabs with dynamic data in viewpager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dynamic, android-tablayout

[image]I need a help. I am developing dynamic tabs with dynamic data in viewpager fragment's list. Somehow i got the dynamic tabs and hit API in placeholder fragment to get the recyclerview list.
there are two issue. 1. design is overlapping the tabs and 2. its loading 3rd id data first.
here is the code.
here is main class

```
public class NewsFeed extends Fragment {

    private static RecyclerView listView;
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private List<BlogCatData> list = new ArrayList<BlogCatData>();
    private BlogCatListAdaptor adapter;
    private String item;
    private ArrayList<BlogCatData> dataModelList = new ArrayList<BlogCatData>();
    private ArrayList<String> CatTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<String> CatIdList = new ArrayList<>();
    private View view1;
    private View v;
//    private ArrayAdapter<BlogCatData> adapter;

    public NewsFeed() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, container, false);

        getAllBlogCat();

        return v;
    }

    private void setViewIDs() {

        tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.container);
        setUpViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    private void getAllBlogCat() {
//        avi.show();
        apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<BlogCatModel> call = apiInterface.GETBlogCategory();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<BlogCatModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BlogCatModel> call, retrofit2.Response<BlogCatModel> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    CatIdList.clear();
                    list = response.body().getDATA();

                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                        CatTitleList.add(list.get(i).getTITLE());
                        CatIdList.add(list.get(i).getID());
                    }

                    Log.v("CatTitle", CatTitleList.toString());
                    Log.v("CatId", CatIdList.toString());

                    setViewIDs();

//                    adapter.setPostList(list)


                } else {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jObjError.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BlogCatModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        for (int i = 0; i < CatTitleList.size(); i++) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id", CatIdList.get(i));
            PlaceholderFragment categoryList = new PlaceholderFragment();
            categoryList.setArguments(bundle);
            sectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(categoryList, CatTitleList.get(i));
        }
        sectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private final static String TAG = PlaceholderFragment.class.getSimpleName();
        private static String item;
        private static ArrayList<String> dataModelList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //        private ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
        private RecyclerView listView;
        private List<BlogData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        private BlogListAdaptor blogListAdaptor;
        private static String id;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();

            id = CatIdList.get(sectionNumber);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("ID", id);

            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__newsfeed_placeholder, container, false);
            listView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

            getBlog(Id);
            setBlog();

            return view;
        }


        private void getBlog(String id) {
            ApiInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<BlogModel> call = apiInterface.getNewsByCategory(id);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<BlogModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<BlogModel> call, retrofit2.Response<BlogModel> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        dataList = response.body().getDATA();

                        blogListAdaptor.setPostList(dataList);


                    } else {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jObjError.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<BlogModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    call.cancel();
                }
            });
        }


    private void setBlog() {
        blogListAdaptor = new BlogListAdaptor(getActivity(), dataList);
        listView.setAdapter(blogListAdaptor);
        listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        listView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

}

    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 0);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {

            mFragmentList.add(fragment);

            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return mFragmentTitleList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position) {

            }
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }
    }

}
```

and here is the adapter class for recyclerview

```
public class BlogListAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogListAdaptor.MyViewHlder> {
private Activity activity;
private List<BlogData> list;

private boolean valid;
private EditText name, email, phone, date, noOfGuest, msg;
private Spinner partyMode, timeSlot;
private AlertDialog alertDialog;
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
private String PartyModeStr, TimeSlotStr;
private String Id;
private String title;

public BlogListAdaptor(Activity activity, List<BlogData> list) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
}

public void setPostList(List<BlogData> dataList) {
    list = dataList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHlder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_list_layout, viewGroup, false);
    MyViewHlder my = new MyViewHlder(view);
    return my;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHlder myViewHlder, int i) {

    myViewHlder.Title.setText(list.get(i).getTITLE());
    myViewHlder.Author.setText(list.get(i).getAUTHOR());

    if (list.get(i).getIMGSRC() != null)
    Glide.with(activity).load(Constant.ImgRoot + list.get(i).getIMGSRC())
            .into(myViewHlder.Image);

    myViewHlder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Id", list.get(i).getID());
            intent.putExtra("Title", list.get(i).getTITLE());
            intent.putExtra("Author", list.get(i).getAUTHOR());
            intent.putExtra("Content", list.get(i).getCONTENT());
            activity.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

class MyViewHlder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView Title, Author;
    private ImageView Image;
    private CardView cardview;

    public MyViewHlder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        cardview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);

    }
}
```

}

Please help me out, to call api...

```
fragment_newsfeed_placeholder

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

fragment_news_feed

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabTextColor="#ffffff" />

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs" />
```

Comment: for design is overlapping the tabs can you post your design as well?

Comment: @nik Yes I have updated

Comment: @nik Do you have any solution?